# Windows 10 and GPMC Class Library - where is it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have installed **RSAT for Windows 10** and this should give me the above class lib. But I cannot find it!

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff182374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to be outdated, its talking about win vista and win7!. Following this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff519502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) under %windir%\assembly\gac_msil I should find the necessary assembly to add to my Visual Studio Project. Unfortunately I do not have an assembly named Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management there.

I can start the server manager and I can also open the Group Policy Management console, but I can't find the assemblies! Anybody knows what I am missing? Where can I find these assemblies under Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. if you are still looking, on Windows 10 RSAT installs the Microsoft.grouppolicy.management dlls into %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL. You can browse to this dll to add it as a reference to your .Net project. Also you don't need to "Turn Windows features on or off" as RSAT doesn't appear in the list and this was installed by default. The Microsoft article is out of date as you mention. Hope that helps.